# Why are 'top' and 'pop' seen as undeclared identifiers when I subclass the STL stack class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm feeling rather stupid - must be missing something silly --- I wanted to subclass the generic STL stack class so that I could extend it with a combined **top** followed by **pop** operation but my compiler is telling me that both **top** and **pop** are undeclared identifiers.

```
template <typename T>
class MyStack : public stack<T>
{
   public:
      T PopTop()  // Convenience - combined top and pop in one go
         {
            T result = top();
            pop();
            return result;
         }
};
```

I note that I can fix this problem by writing

```
   T result = stack<T>::top();
```

but why isn't **top** seen automatically given the stack class is directly inherited?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `this->top()` also works. This happens whenever a base class depends on a template parameter.

Comment: Be careful about inheriting from STL classes - they lack virtual destructors and are not intended to be inherited from.

Comment: Templates can be specialized.  For this reason, it can not be assumed that `pop()` means `stack<T>::pop()`.  For a given `T`, the member function `pop()` might not exist and some other `pop()` would be a better match.

Comment: Thank you for all these useful tips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't descend from `std` classes, rather use private member (composition) and delegate functions - that's a common warning.

With that said, the error is because a base class with a template argument is not considered in ADL lookup regarding the descendant class. You might have `using stack<T>::pop;` and similar declarations for each function that you plan to use in `MyStack`.

Comment: I am aware of the arguments for composition, etc --- however, in this case, I did not want to add any fields, simply wanted a single convenience method and composition seemed overkill for the intended purpose. That said, I appreciate the answer (did not remember that ADL won't work in that situation - as I said, I was missing something stupid)

Comment: @David Yes, I had that feeling in the past - however, in many cases it turns out to be a maintenance nightmare compared to a public decorator (i.e., `template <typename T> struct myStack { /* your methods */ operator const std::stack<T>&() const { return s_; } operator std::stack<T>&() { return s_; }  std::stack<T> s_; /* note that s_ is publicly accessible */ };`).

Comment: Sure --- I'm aware of the Decorator design pattern  (and trust me, the maintenance consequences of poor decisions!) but for this particular purpose, I just felt it was overkill when all I wanted was the equivalent of "extend" rather than "encapsulate" for a single method that would be useful only locally.  Regular inheritance still has some value :-)    If I was building something within a corporate environment or that would have to be used by others, I would have gone that way but at least I learned something about ADL that I didn't know.